# How to remove a single line of data from one csv and write it to a different csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv, tkinter

I am trying to make my confirm button activate removing the park name from the existing park and writing it to a new csv of parks visited. So the first time the program would need to create the new csv if it doesn't exist. Basically it will keep a log of parks visited in the new csv. Here's what I've tried but it is not executing (see `def confirm_park()`). I'm a little lost. Any pointers or tips to help me move forward?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas
import random
import csv

BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#006600"
BUTTON_COLOR = "#6699ff"


# try:
#   data = pandas.read_csv("data/stl_parks_visited.csv")
# except FileNotFoundError:
#   original_data = pandas.read_csv("data/stl_parks_list.csv")
#   to_learn = original_data.to_dict(orient="records")
# else:
#   to_learn = data.to_dict(orient="records")



def new_park():
    with open("stl_parks_list.csv") as f:
      park = f.readlines()
      chosen_park = random.choice(park)
      canvas.itemconfig(park_text, text = chosen_park)  


def confirm_park():
    park.remove(chosen_park)
    print(len(park))
    data = pandas.DataFrame(park)
    data.to_csv("data/stl_parks_visited.csv", index=False)


# --- UI Setup ---
window = Tk()
window.title("St. Louis Parks at Random")
window.config(padx=20, pady=20, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=100, bg="white")
park_text = canvas.create_text(
            150, 
            65, 
            text='Ready, set,\n"GET PARK"', 
            width=280,
            fill=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
            font=("Ariel", 20, "italic")
            )
canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20, sticky="NESW")
# arch_img = PhotoImage(file="gateway-arch-park.png")
# canvas.create_image(226, 159, image=arch_img)
# canvas.config(bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, highlightthickness=0)
# canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='')


# --- Label ---
website_label = Label(text="St. Louis Parks at Random", fg="white", bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
website_label.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2)


# --- Buttons ---

# "Get Park" button generates a random park name from the stl_parks_list.csv
get_park_button = Button(text="GET PARK", width=20, bg=BUTTON_COLOR, font=("bold"), command=new_park)
get_park_button.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky='', pady=20) 

# "Confirm" button cornfirms that you want to visit this park. The park name will then be moved to a new csv of stl_visited_parks.csv and removed from the stl_parks_list.csv.
confirm_button = Button(text="CONFIRM", width=10, bg=BUTTON_COLOR, font=("bold"), command=confirm_park)
confirm_button.grid(column=0, row=3)

# Push the "Skip" button to skip the park and get a different suggestion. Park names remain on the parks list until they are confirmed.
skip_button = Button(text="SKIP", width=10, bg=BUTTON_COLOR, font=("bold"), command=new_park)
skip_button.grid(column=1, row=3)



new_park()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: When asking question here, it's best to provide [mre] but unfortunately there's a lot of unrelated stuff currently in your question — much more than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

1. `park` and `chosen_park` are local variables inside `new_park()`, so they cannot be accessed inside `confirm_park()`.  They need to be declared global inside `new_park()`.
2. You should read the park list outside `new_park()` and just randomly choose a park inside the function.
3. you are not saving the `chosen_park` to `stl_parks_visited.csv`.
4. `park` is a list of park names with trailing "\n" in each park name.  Use `park = f.read().splitlines()` to remove the trailing "\n".

According to your code, it seems like that `stl_park_list.csv` contains the park name only in each line.  So using `pandas` to convert the list `park` to dataframe and save the dataframe to file is not necessary. Just use simple file operation to append `chosen_park` to output file is enough.

Below are modified `new_park()` and `confirm_park()`:

```py
with open("stl_parks_list.csv") as f:
    park = f.read().splitlines()

def new_park():
    global chosen_park
    chosen_park = random.choice(park)
    canvas.itemconfig(park_text, text=chosen_park)  


def confirm_park():
    park.remove(chosen_park)
    print(len(park))
    with open("data/stl_parks_visited.csv", "a") as f:
        print(chosen_park, file=f)
```

With the above change, the <kbd>GET PARK</kbd> button is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mode='a'` argument in `.to_csv()` method and write a header only if file doesn't exists:

```
import os

def confirm_park():
    park.remove(chosen_park)
    print(len(park))
    data = pandas.DataFrame(park)
    file = "data/stl_parks_visited.csv"
    data.to_csv(file, index=False, mode='a', header=os.path.isfile(file))
```